# One time generic event call?

Tags: c#

What I am trying to achieve is to create convenient syntax for calling a callback on an event only once.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Once<T>(this EventHandler<T> @event, EventHandler<T> callback)
    {
        EventHandler<T> cb = null;
        cb = (object that, T info) => {
            if (callback != null) {
                callback(that, info);
            }
            @event -= cb;
        };
        @event += cb;
    }
}
```

This should allow us to write something like this:

```
obj.OnSomething.Once((sender, obj) => Console.WriteLine(obj));
```

Note that OnSomething is an event EventHandler of some type.

The problem is that I get the error message:

> Error CS0070: The event `SharpTox.Core.Tox.OnFriendMessage' can only
>   appear on the left hand side of += or -= when used outside of the type`
>   SharpTox.Core.Tox' (CS0070) (SharpTox.Tests)

Is there no way to achieve this that easily? Do I have to remove event from OnSomething and make it a simple delegate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't have a nice syntax here. Like the error message says, all you can do with an event field from outside of its defining class is referencing it at the left of `+=` or `-=`.

Here's the method that [Rx](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Main/) uses to bind an observable to an event:

```
var observable = Observable.FromEventPattern(
    handler => obj.OnSomething += handler,
    handler => obj.OnSomething -= handler);
```

Basically, `FromEventPattern` is a helper that takes two lambdas: one for subscription, and the other for unsubscription. You could use a similar pattern, or just use Rx to achieve the same effect:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern(h => obj.OnSomething += h, h => obj.OnSomething -= h)
          .Take(1)
          .Subscribe(e => ...);
```

On a side note, this will keep a reference to `obj` from the lambda used in `Subscribe` (there are intermediary glue objects but this is irrelevant). This means that if the event is never called, and if the lambda is long-lived, then `obj` won't be eligible for GC (a situation called *event memory leak*). This may or may not be a problem for your case.

Comment: "Unfortunately, you can't have a nice syntax here." This is due to C#'s language specification. [Here is the petition to fix that](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4134291-make-events-first-class-values-in-c) NB. F# Can do this nicely.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to return the callback. In the extension method the callback is deleted/removed. The drawback of this approach is still the fact that the event handler function needs to be defined separately and can not be a lambda.

The extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{   
    public static EventHandler<T> Once<T>(this Action<Object, T> callback)
    {
        return (Object s, T e) => 
        {
            if (callback != null) {
                callback(s, e);
                callback = null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

A demo class that has different events:

```
public class Demo
{
    public event EventHandler<String> StringEvent = null;
    public event EventHandler<Int32> IntEvent = null;

    public void NotifyOnWork()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            if (this.StringEvent != null) { this.StringEvent(this, i.ToString()); }
            if (this.IntEvent != null) { this.IntEvent(this, i); }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage of the Demo class:

```
var demo = new Demo();
Action<Object, String> handlerString = (s, e) =>  { Console.WriteLine("echo string {0}", e); };
Action<Object, Int32> handlerInt = (s, e) =>  { Console.WriteLine("echo int {0}", e); };

demo.StringEvent += handlerString.Once();
demo.IntEvent += handlerInt.Once();
demo.StringEvent += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("i = {0}", e); 
demo.NotifyOnWork();
```

And the output is:

```
0
echo string 0
i = 0
echo int 0
1
i = 1
2
i = 2
3
i = 3
4
i = 4
```

Comment: The downside is that you never unsubscribe from the events, so the event handlers stay forever and degrade the performance over time.

Comment: Yes, it degrades performance, but I need this only to write nice looking test cases, so the syntax is clearer and the performance impact is neglectible.

Answer (score 0):

You've posted an answer to a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52738813/2060966).

The syntax would look somewhat like this:

```
obj.Event += (s, e) =>
{
    Detach(s, nameof(obj.Event));
    // ..do stuff..
};
```

The `Detach` method would look like this and can be put anywhere you like (most likely a static helper class):

```
public static void Detach(object obj, string eventName)
{
    var caller = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
    var type = obj.GetType();
    foreach (var field in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
    {
        if (typeof(Delegate).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType))
        {
            var handler = (field.GetValue(obj) as Delegate)?.GetInvocationList().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Method.Equals(caller));
            if (handler != null)
            {
                type.GetEvent(eventName).RemoveEventHandler(obj, handler);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```