# Attach event handler to be called only once

Tags: c#, events, extension-methods

I am currently trying to write an extension function to be able to easily attach an action that is only used once when the event is fired, then unsubscribed.

I am trying something like this:

```
public static void AttachOnce<TEventArgs>([NotNull] this EventHandler<TEventArgs> me, [NotNull] Action<object, TEventArgs> action)
    where TEventArgs : System.EventArgs
{
    var handler = me;
    EventHandler<TEventArgs> wrappedAction = null;
    wrappedAction = (sender, args) =>
    {
        action(sender, args);
        handler -= wrappedAction;
    };
    handler += wrappedAction;
}
```

But ReSharper complains on the unsubscribe that `handler` is **"Access to modified closure"**.

I know what this means, so I made the local variable for the closure already, but it doesn't seem to resolve it. What is failing here?

The direct hard-coded code works. Something like this:

```
var file = new FileSystemWatcher("path/to/file");

FileSystemEventHandler handler = null;
handler = (sender, args) =>
{
    // My action code here
    file.Changed -= handler;
};
file.Changed += handler;
```

#### EDIT 1 (2018-10-09 11:43 CET):

I may just have been too fast, asking a question before thoroughly thinking it through.
You can't create extension methods on Events. At all. It's just not possible in C#. So I can't even test why ReSharper is complaining and if it is right, because a call like `file.Changed.AttachOnce(action)` is not valid. It says **"The event 'Changed' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -="**.

I have found some more sources for similar requests/questions:
http://www.hardkoded.com/blog/csharp-wishlist-extension-for-events
[One time generic event call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766873/one-time-generic-event-call)

Comment: Please be more specific about "doesn't seem to resolve it". What exactly happens? (or does not happen)

Comment: Apart from the resharper error: does your approach work? Also you could have a look at the compiled code and try to spot if there is anything wrong with your construct after compilation. see: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALAPgAgBgARwIwG4CwAoOBmFVCFAJkIHYkBvHJOlAtYuKJAQQBcOBDAYwAsA8gDteAUwA8AFQCiANzHCObAE4BzAM4A+ABQd+ASw1J5ijgAluwgCYAbMSummlqzVqQBbMQBpCJCQD2wABWYrwcvrIKLuraSHwcBgHCAJS09BkA7vwOYkhRZq7GIIQAdM7Ksel0NNgZGXLcKkj8VnYOSAC8nmJYdfV0FZY29o4FMW5ImSrcAA6zYtZoZN3CAK62tn0DdNNzC0uoK0g6GorWDr5NmildWtX1tTv1CUnCp+eX8bEp28/0rRGHQAtN09vNFss/gMAL7Q+qA9rNADUYJmEMOJHhMJwMKAA

Comment: You might have missed to set `EnableRaisingEvents` to `true`? But then your "hard-coded" code wouldn't work either.

Comment: I may just have been too fast, asking a question before thoroughly thinking it through. You can't create extension methods on Events. At all. It's just not possible in C#. So I can't even test why ReSharper is complaining and if it is right, because a call like `file.Changed.AttachOnce(action)` is not valid.
It says **"The event 'Changed' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -="**.

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about a different but much simpler approach, using a "self-detaching" inline handler which would be used like this:

```
obj.Event += (s, e) =>
{
    Detach(obj, nameof(obj.Event));
    // ..do stuff..
};
```

The `Detach` method would look like this and could be put anywhere you like (most likely a static helper class):

```
public static void Detach(object obj, string eventName)
{
    var caller = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
    var type = obj.GetType();
    foreach (var field in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
    {
        if (typeof(Delegate).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType))
        {
            var handler = (field.GetValue(obj) as Delegate)?.GetInvocationList().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Method.Equals(caller));
            if (handler != null)
            {
                type.GetEvent(eventName).RemoveEventHandler(obj, handler);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So for your example the code would look like this:

```
file.Changed += (s, e) =>
{
    Detach(file, nameof(file.Changed));
    // My action code here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it's okay.
ReSharper simply warns that `handler` is different between the time you declare and the time it is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how exactly you want to design your extension method, but maybe this will get you started:

```
public static void OnChangedOnce(this FileSystemWatcher instance, Action<object, FileSystemEventArgs> action)
{
    var file = instance;
    var wrappedAction = action;
    FileSystemEventHandler handler = null;
    handler = (object sender, FileSystemEventArgs args) =>
    {
        wrappedAction(sender, args);
        file.Changed -= handler;
    };
    file.Changed += handler;
    file.EnableRaisingEvents = true; // mandatory
}

var file = new FileSystemWatcher("path/to/file");
file.OnChangedOnce((sender, args)) =>
{
    // your action here
});
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my original intent, to create a generic extension method that I can use on every event to subcribe an action that gets called once. Your extension method is specific to `FileSystemWatcher` and even this one event `Changed`.

But as I've commented on my question above already, this seems to be the only option to generate a shorthand. Because there are no extension methods on events :-/

Comment: @Wolfsblvt Yep that's why I asked how you wanted to design your extension method in the first place, because the signature seemed odd and I had no idea how you were planning to call it.

Comment: I thought about calling it on the event of the object itself, like I've seen implementations of the "Safe raise event" feature already. But that seems to be different, becaue you are executing a delegate or something like this.

Comment: @Wolfsblvt You cannot access the event from outside the declaring type except with +/-

Comment: @Wolfsblvt I've dived a little deeper into this topic as I found it very intriguing. It would be possible, but VERY complicated. Also using the solution would not be a lot more convenient than hard-coding it, so the effort is not really worth it. If you're interested I can tell you more about my findings.

Comment: Would be happy to hear more about it. It's an interesting topic, and I am always looking for shortcuts and extensions to save time and work while coding.
Maybe go ahead and edit your answer?

Comment: @Wolfsblvt Check out my other answer, see if that helps you.